# I am trying to implement elastic search using searchkick gem in my rails app (rails 6). I get SystemStackError when reindexing my model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=Restaurant

rake aborted!
SystemStackError: stack level too deep

Comment: There are too few information to help you! please copy Restaurant class here

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. Here is the code of my restaurant model:

Comment: ```class Restaurant < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :image

  has_many :reviews

  validates :name, :address, :phone, :website, :image, presence: true
  validates :phone, format: { with: /\A\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}\z/,
    message: "must be in the format (123) 456-7890" }
  validates :website, format: { with: /\Ahttps?:\/\/.*\z/,
    message: "must start with http:// or https://" }

  searchkick
  
end```

Answer (score 1):

This is not due to Elasticsearch and it seems you have **non-terminating recursion** in your code which caused this error, please refer to [this NR blog](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/ruby-agent/troubleshooting/systemstackerror-stack-level-too-deep) for detailed explanation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I only get this error after adding `searchkick` gem to my app. I get this error even after creating objects of my model. Thats why I thought it may be related to using `searchkick` and `elasticsearch`.